# Session based flash message doesn't work in else part of PHP code

Tags: php, session

In my contact.php page, I am sending emails to admin and user after passing the validation. The code looks something below:

```
// If any validation error occurs
if(count($errors) > 0)
{
  // show error messages
}
else
{
  // sending emails to admin and user
  set_flash_msg('msg', 'Thank you for contacting us.', 'success');
  redirect_to('contact');
}
```

But the code in `else` part related flash message doesn't work. If I put this code in `if` part then it works without any issue. The function set_flash_msg() is responsible to create session based flash message. Its code is below:

```
// Set flash message
function set_flash_msg($name, $msg, $class)
{
    global $name;
    if(empty($_SESSION[$name]) && empty($_SESSION[$name . '_class']))
    {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $msg;
        $_SESSION[$name . '_class'] = $class;
    }
}
```

To display this message, another function is called below the above code as:

```
// Show flash message
get_flash_msg();
```

There is no issue regarding session setting because in `if` part, it works fine. The same logic and coding flow is used in my backend too where I set flash message when a new page is added and show the flash message on page listing page.php. If it works at there then why it doesn't work on my front-end contact.php page? Any idea?

Comment: `session_start()` on contact.php?

Comment: the include file contains all necessary common code related to project along with session_start() at top. And this file is included at top of contact.php page.

Comment: If it works in your `if` part, maybe `$errors` isn't empty?

Comment: `global $name;` and then using param `$name` is going to cause problems. Considering the global will override the local.

Comment: No, if it was not empty then in else part redirection code couldn't work. Its only flash message that doesn't work in else part.

Comment: Another thing to mention is that you are only setting your flash message if the session has no 'msg' already defined. If you define two 'msg' in the same session, only the first will work (unless you are clearing this at some point). Logical behaviour would be either to override the existing with each call, or to collect them together in an array e.g. like [drupal_set_message](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) would do.

Comment: @Pebbl, you're awesome! I had never thought about it and not others as well with whom I shared my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my contact.php page, I am grabbing the form values particularly "name" as:

```
// Preparing form variables
$name = isset($_POST['txtname']) ? $db_obj->sanitize_input($_POST['txtname']) : '';
```

The local variable $name conflicts with global variable $name in set_flash_msg() function. Changing $name to $uname in above code solved the problem.